# Get Incremental index for specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the incremental index when note exists for the row. I am trying to achieve the same with ROW_Number() but it seems there is a problem with the method being used to generate it.

```
SELECT *                    RowNo,
       (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN LEN(Value) > 0 THEN ROW_NUMBER()
                                            OVER (
                                              ORDER BY ID)
                 ELSE ''
               END
        FROM   Dictionary
        WHERE  ID = ABC.ID) Note
FROM   ABCD AS ABC WITH(NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN XYZ AS XYZ WITH(NOLOCK)
               ON ABC.Id = XYZ.ID
WHERE  ABC.Id = 10
```

output expected:

```
    ID Name Note
    1  A    1
    2  B    
    3  C    2
    4  D    
    5  E    
    6  F    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subquery isn't needed here, and you want to use the `partition by` argument to separate `values` having `len(value)>0` from those having no value:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    CASE WHEN LEN(Value)>0 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CASE WHEN LEN(Value)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ORDER BY ID) ELSE '' END as Note       
FROM  ABCD AS ABC WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN XYZ AS XYZ WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON ABC.Id = XYZ.ID
Where ABC.Id = 10
```

Comment: `CASE ... integer_expression ELSE '' END` will end up implicitly casting '' to `int` which gives zero.

Comment: Good catch. This is the OP's code, so I'll wait for his input. He will either have to accept the zeros, remove the else and accept nulls, or cast his row_number as a varchar so he can have a blank.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you need to change the approach to make the Dictionary query the "main" query.   It's hard to say without knowing exactly what your tables look like.   Which Table does the "Id" in your expected output come from?

Try like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Note
  FROM Dictionary WHERE ID=10
  AND LEN(Value)>0
)
SELECT ABC.ID, [Name], cte.Note
FROM  ABCD AS ABC WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN XYZ AS XYZ WITH(NOLOCK) ON ABC.Id = XYZ.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte ON ABC.Id=cte.ID
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` exclude values from `ABC` and `XYZ` tables that don't match the `cte`? I think you want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to not exclude any records not matching the `cte`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I was originally going to .. ah never mind, I'll edit.